# How do I define a custom command line argument that I can pass to my selenium test script that I run with nose?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose, nosetests

I am writing automated selenium test scripts in Python, supported by nose. My goal is to be able to change the URL against which my selenium tests run, at the point where I start the test scripts, so that I can have the same script run on the same machine but targeting different environments (test, acceptance, perhaps even production) without having to manually edit the script.

To accomplish this goal, I want to define a custom command-line argument for my tests. I've been searching for a way to do this for a while now but all I can really find is people saying "you shouldn't want to do this in nose since your tests shouldn't depend on command line arguments to pass".

That seems like it is a very reasonable viewpoint when it concerns unit testing, but in functional testing, a case like mine I would argue that it makes a lot more sense. My script is purposely written in a way that will allow it to be reused on different instances of the same codebase, although I may find myself with some parts of some tests that I will not want to execute on certain environments. As an example, performing an order on a webshop is a good idea on most environments, but on the production environment it's probably not a very good idea.

Is there really no way to do this (cleanly) with my current choice of tools?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [nose-testconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/). This allows you to define either a configuration file (of various formats - INI style, YAML, etc) or even just pass things directly via the command line invocation of your tests.  You import the module in your tests, and that gives you access to these values.  Pretty easy.  I have had to do this myself before where I wanted my tests to compare some generated data to somewhere that had to be passed in to the tests.  So certainly legitimate reasons happen.

That said, consider whether you are better off creating a test user in your codebase that orders could be made against, it's always nice to see all of your tests running regardless of where its run.